# In how many rows does each character occurs in a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, character, rows

I have the following 2D array in Java:

```
String[][] rows = {
    {"M","O","N","K","E","Y"},
    {"D","O","N","K","E","Y"},
    {"M","A","K","E"},
    {"M","U","C","K","Y"},
    {"C","O","O","K","Y"},
    };
```

Now i want to make a list with the numbers of rows of the array that each character occurs in.

So this must be the result:

```
M occurs in 3 rows, O occurs in 3 rows, N occurs in 2 rows, A occurs in 1 row, etc...
```

(The last row has two O's but i that case it only needs to count one)

This are the steps i already took:

Step 1: Looped trough the array and counted how many times each character occured in the whole array.

Step 2: Looped though the array and looked if the character already occured in the whole array. (boolean)

These two steps helped me a little bit but i can't figure out how i can compare every row apart for each of the characters. I think i need to check every "character + row combination" together and compare it to every other combination but i don't know how to do that exactly.

Comment: You should use a one dimensional `string` array or a two dimensional `char` array if all the element will look like these ones.

Answer (score 0):

So, first You can loop through the whole array, to find every different letter.

In a two dimensional array, You could store the letters and the count of the rows they appear in.

Then You just need to go throught the rows and check the letters You stored before. The easiest(but not the most elegant) solution would be the following: You go through each row as many times as many different letter occured in the whole 2D array. If You find a letter, You increment its counter in Your other 2D array, and go to the next letter. If You checked a row for every letter, You go to the next row.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

1. Initialize a `Map<Character, Integer>` representing the number of occurences for each character in your array
2. For each row, put all the characters in a `Set<Character>`
3. For each character in this set, add or increment the number of occurences in your map

The map you initialized then contains all the information you need

---

Java:

```
public static Map<Character, Integer> countCharInRow(char[][] myArray) {
    Map<Character, Integer> charOccurences = new HashMap<>();
    Set<Character> rowCharacters = new HashSet<>();
    for(char[] row : myArray) {
        for(char charInArray = row) { // put all the chars on the line in the set
            rowCharacters.add(row);
        }
        for(char charInSet : rowCharacters) {
            Integer occurences = charOccurences.get(charInSet);
            if(occurences == null) { // first occurence
                charOccurences.put(charInSet, 1);
            } else {  // increment
                charOccurences.put(charInSet, occurences.intValue() + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return charOccurences;
}
```